# Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector with parameter

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to create a LINQ expression selector to accomodate another IQueryable as a parameter. The dot.net fiddle is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nAMqeU)

I am trying to code the **CustomSelector** to accept an `IQueryable parameter` and apply it to the selector depending on case.

Also, I want to include in the call of **CustomSelector** the value of each row to apply to the IQueryable parameter.

This way I will not have to write 2 Custom selectors.

*The alternative is **GetMyData2** function.*

The test code is below:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EntityDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class TestController 
{
    public List<Entity> entityList { get; set; }


    public List<EntityDto> GetMyData(string condition)
    {
        List<Entity> sourceEntityList = new List<Entity>();
        List<EntityDto> returnEntityList = new List<EntityDto>();

        switch(condition)
        {
            case "A":       
            returnEntityList = sourceEntityList.Where(x=>x.Name == "A").Select(y=>CustomSelector(sourceEntityList.Where(z=>z.Name=x.Name)));
        return returnEntityList;
            break;
        case "B":       
        default:
            returnEntityList = sourceEntityList.Where(x=>x.Name == "B").Select(y=>CustomSelector(sourceEntityList.Where(z=>z.Name != x.Name)));
        return returnEntityList;
            break;
        }

    }

    public List<EntityDto> GetMyData2(string condition)
    {
        List<Entity> sourceEntityList = new List<Entity>();
        List<EntityDto> returnEntityList = new List<EntityDto>();

        switch(condition)
        {
            case "A":       
            returnEntityList = sourceEntityList.Where(x=>x.Name == "A").Select(ent=>
                                                                               new EntityDto()
                {
                    Id = ent.Id
                    ,
                    Name = ent.Name                                       
                    ,
                    Count =  sourceEntityList.Count(z=>z.Name== ent.Name)
                }
                                                                              ).ToList();
        return returnEntityList;
            break;
        case "B":       
        default:
            returnEntityList = sourceEntityList.Where(x=>x.Name == "B").Select(ent=>
                                                                               new EntityDto()
                {
                    Id = ent.Id
                    ,
                    Name = ent.Name                                       
                    ,
                    Count =  sourceEntityList.Count(z=>z.Name != ent.Name)
                }
                                                                              ).ToList();
        return returnEntityList;
            break;
        }

    }

    protected Func<Entity, EntityDto> CustomSelector(IQueryable<Entity> paramQuery)
        {

                return ent => new EntityDto()
                {
                    Id = ent.Id
                    ,
                    Name = ent.Name                                       
                    ,
                    Count =  paramQuery.Count()
                };

        }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?...

Comment: How can I create a LINQ expression selector to accomodate another IQueryable as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

What are you asking is not possible w/o some expression tree manipulation.

You can use some 3rd party packages like [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) (`AsExpandable` / `Invoke`) or [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), but here is a custom solution based on expression prototype and simple parameter replacer.

*Parameter replacer:*

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

*CustomSelector:*

```
protected Expression<Func<Entity, EntityDto>> CustomSelector(Expression<Func<Entity, IQueryable<Entity>>> paramQuery)
{
    Expression<Func<Entity, IQueryable<Entity>, EntityDto>> prototype = (e, q) => new EntityDto
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Name = e.Name,
        Count = q.Count(),
    };
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, EntityDto>>(
        prototype.Body
            .ReplaceParameter(prototype.Parameters[0], paramQuery.Parameters[0])
            .ReplaceParameter(prototype.Parameters[1], paramQuery.Body),
        paramQuery.Parameters[0]);
}
```

*Usage:*

```
public List<EntityDto> GetMyData(string condition)
{
    var sourceEntityList = new List<Entity>().AsQueryable();
    switch (condition)
    {
        case "A":
            return sourceEntityList.Where(x => x.Name == "A")
                .Select(CustomSelector(x => sourceEntityList.Where(y => y.Name == x.Name))).ToList();
        case "B":
        default:
            return sourceEntityList.Where(x => x.Name == "B")
                .Select(CustomSelector(x => sourceEntityList.Where(y => y.Name != x.Name))).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Do not know why the downvotes though, they did not leave a comment.

So I would be better off just writing the different selector for each case I have?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the last question about each case. The sample shows only one `CustomSelector` method, so does the answer.

Comment: Maybe replacement of all parameters at once (like `prototype.Body.BetaReduce(paramQuery.Parameters[0], paramQuery.Body)`) will be more beautiful?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Most probably :) I've just tried to keep it simple and short as for most of the SO posts.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I mean, would I be better off using the GetMyData2 function instead?

Comment: It depends of how many real cases you have and how many properties do you set inside the `new { ... }`. Generally speaking, the above `ExpressionUtils` is a helper you could use in many other scenarios, prototype allows you to easily create compile time expressions, and building the final lambda from other expressions with parameter replacement is relatively easy. So I guess it's up to you to decide which approach is easier/better for you.